# If I wanted to create my own AS (autonomous system), how would I go about it?

Tags: networking

What kind of network equipment would I need? How would I connect it to the network? What organizations would I need to talk to to get everything set up?

Answer (score 2):

- You need to get an AS number from your RIR.
- You need to get a public address prefix, no longer than `/24`. ISPs will not            advertise a prefix longer than `/24`. The
  RIRs are out of public addresses to assign, so you will need to get
  it on the open market, or from your ISP.
- You need a router than can run BGP, and configure it to exchange
  prefixes via BGP with your ISP.
- You need an ISP and a contract to do the above. Many ISPs will want
  proof that you know how to configure BGP.